# Why doesnt add layers on redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to add an array of layers using redux.

First, I create an array of promises.

Secnod, I use Promise.all with promises array and send to database all the info and returns all layers created on database.

Third, totalLayers contains current layers with new layers from database.

My problem is that launch dispatch and draw layers on my map, but dont update the array of redux with totalLayers.

SET_MAP_LAYERS update layers stored in Store as you can see in mapGlLayers variable.

What I'm doing wrong??

```
static addMultipleLayersFromDataSet(layers, source) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        let mapGlLayers = store.getStore().getState().maplayers.maplayers.slice();
        let position = mapGlLayers.filter(l => l.name).length;
        let promises = layers.map( layer => uploadMultipleLayers(layer, source, position++)); 

        Promise.all(promises)
        .then(downloadedlayers => {
            let totalLayers = [...mapGlLayers, ...downloadedlayers];
            dispatch({
                type: LayerTypeConstants.SET_MAP_LAYERS,
                payload: totalLayers
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch({
                type: LayerTypeConstants.MAPLAYER_ERROR,
                payload: error
            });
        });
    };
}
```

REDUCER:

```
import { LayerTypeConstants } from '../utils/ReduxConstants';

const initialStateApp = {
    maplayers: [],
};

export default function LayerReducer(state = initialStateApp, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LayerTypeConstants.SET_MAP_LAYERS: {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                maplayers: action.payload
            });
        }
        case LayerTypeConstants.MAPLAYER_ERROR: {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                messageMapLayer: action.payload
            });
        }
        case LayerTypeConstants.INIT_LAYERS:
            return Object.assign({}, initialStateApp);
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Here is an image of my redux state:

[image]

Here is console message with layers:

[image]

Comment: How does your reducer look like?

Answer (score 0):

Promise is a state machine under the hood. State machines perform state transitions. Redux alone is not prepared to handle such transitions so it heeds a helper. I'd suggest reading about Async Redux Actions, [link](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions). The two widely used helpers are [redux-thunks](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) and [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html).

Comment: I'm using redux-thunk

Comment: Indeed, you are :)  The reducer `LayerReducer` doesn't seem to handle the `MAPLAYER_ERROR` action which means the reducer returns unchanged `state`in response for this action. So maybe one of the promises gets rejected and the reducer ensures nothing has changed.

Comment: I think I should clear node modules and install again... because it's never has happened.